# How to access a public property from another project's c# class from WinJS

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winjs

I have two projects, one is in C# and other is WinJS. In the C# project there is a class and I have to access the class properties from within a winJS JavaScript file.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to convert (if it's not already) your C# project to a WinRT Component and then consume that component in the WinJS class. Then in your JavaScript, you would instantiate an object out of your class and would have full access to its properties.

```
var o = new MyCSharpProjectNamespace.MyType();
o.property1 = "Hello, Aunt Mildred!";
```

If your C# project is a Windows 8 project or a Windows Phone 8 project or a Console Application or any other type, then you can't do what you're asking. It has to be a WinRT Component. If it is a Windows Class Library, then it should be easy enough to convert to a component, but if it's anything else, then it will be a matter of "refactoring" - that is pulling the functionality (perhaps just the class in question) out of that project into a *new* WinRT Component project (using File | New Project | Visual C# | Windows Store | Windows Runtime Component).
Best to you!

Comment: I believe from the WinJS project it'll be seen starting with lower case. At least that's what I saw in my tests. Something like  `o.property1`